# Change an image every time a button is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm hoping to find the right answer here. Here's the scenario..

I have an image (it's a green circle) . And I have three buttons (online, offline, connecting) . Now, I want the image to change every time I press one of these three buttons (it's gonna be on a different div) .

Online - Green Circle image
Offline - Grey Circle image
Connecting - Orange Cirlce image

Anyone who could help me get started? I honestly have no idea how to start.

Comment: Is it a single image where you want to change the "src" property of on button click events?

Can you post the markup of the three buttons and image? (if you have it)

Comment: don't use images (unless there's a logo)

Comment: yes @RobinFrench I want just the src to change :)

Comment: @MaineCoder If ever I use the css equivalent, then how do I change it everytime they press the button

Comment: @user3322081 you would create 3 CSS style rules and then change the class of the element instead of the src

Comment: @RobinFrench aahhh got it! just don't know how to change the class elements using jquery?? :( sorry, i'm really new with jquery/jscript

Comment: @user3322081 Check my answer below, it's got examples of changing the src and class (it's basically the same code to change any HTML attribute in jQuery).

Answer (score 2):

You could use HTML5 Canvas, which allows you to print shapes to the screen using JavaScript.

I have made a mock up for you to see/use:

http://jsfiddle.net/Lukedturnbull/5vz7njzf/

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
var radius = 70;

function drawCircle(colour) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    ctx.fillStyle = colour;
    ctx.fill();
}
```

Comment: Canvas seems like overkill for this situation

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple example without jQuery or images

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #circle 
            {
                height:20px;
                width:20px;
                border-radius:50%
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            function changeColor(color) {
                document.getElementById("circle").style.backgroundColor = color;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="circle"></div>
        <input id="online" type="button" value="Online" onclick="changeColor('#0F0');" />
        <input id="offline" type="button" value="Offline" onclick="changeColor('#CCC');" />
        <input id="connecting" type="button" value="Connecting" onclick="changeColor('#F90');" />   
    </body>
</html>
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/8ke2amoy/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a start using jQuery to bind click events to your buttons.

Html

```
<image class="myimg" id="green" src="green.jpg"/>
<image class="myimg" id="gray" src="gray.jpg"/>
<image class="myimg" id="orange" src="orange.jpg"/>

<button class="mybutton" value="green"/>
<button class="mybutton" value="gray"/>
<button class="mybutton" value="orange"/>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    toggleImage("green");
    $("button.mybutton").on("click",function(){
        toggleImage($(this).val());}
    );
});

function toggleImage(color) {
    $("image.myimg").hide();
    $(document).find("#" + color).show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I did you live demo on jsfiddle to see it working and test it!

```
    <div class="status">
<div class="green online-indicator status-icon">online</div>
<div class="grey offline-indicator status-icon">offline</div>
<div class="orange connecting-indicator status-iconr">connecting</div>
</div>
<button class="online">online</button>
<button class="offline">offline</button>
<button class="connecting">connecting</button>


Your css file




 .status {
        position: relative;
        height: 50px;
    }

    .online-indicator,
    .offline-indicator,
    .connecting-indicator {
        position: absolute;
        display: none;
    }
    .online-indicator { background-color: #5AE64B;}
    .offline-indicator { background-color: #ccc;}
    .connecting-indicator { background-color: #FFB300;}
```

JS

```
$('.online').click(function() {
    $('.status-icon').fadeOut('slow',function(){ 
        $('.online-indicator').fadeIn();
    });

});
$('.offline').click(function() {
    $('.status-icon').fadeOut('slow',function(){ 
        $('.offline-indicator').fadeIn();
    });
});
$('.connecting').click(function() {
    $('.status-icon').fadeOut('slow',function(){ 
        $('.connecting-indicator').fadeIn();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Cowwando/w4pzwvoh/3/
Regards! Please tell me if you need any explanation!

Answer (score 1):

You could have either 3 click events, or a single one with some HTML5 style attributes. There are a couple options presented, changing the src of an image, or using CSS classes. I'll try and detail both in this answer.

(in jQuery)

```
$(function() {
    $("online").on("click", function() {
        $("img").attr("src", "path/to/your/green/image.jpg");
    });
    $("connecting").on("click", function() {
        $("img").attr("src", "path/to/your/grey/image.jpg");
    });
    $("other").on("click", function() {
        $("img").attr("src", "path/to/your/orange/image.jpg");
    });
});
```

You could also create 3 different CSS rules for

```
.online { background: url('path/to/your/green/image.jpg'); }
.connecting { background: url('path/to/your/grey/image.jpg'); }
.other { background: url('path/to/your/orange/image.jpg'); }
```

Then instead of setting the source in the jQuery events, use this

```
 $("img").attr("class", "online/connecting/other"); //depending on button click
```

As an advanced solution, I'd tie it all into one jQuery event, and use a HTML5 data attribute.

```
<input type="button" data-state="online" value="online" />
<input type="button" data-state="online" value="connecting" />
<input type="button" data-state="online" value="other" />
```

And then this jQuery (this assumes you will name your images according to the data-state attribute)

```
$(function() {
    $("input[type='button']").on("click", function() {
        $("img").attr("src", "path/to/you/images/" + $(this).attr("data-state") + ".jpg");
    });
});
```

Or something similar

Answer (score 1):

Here's a CSS-only solution: http://jsfiddle.net/yns6rotz/.

HTML:

```
<div class = "buttonGroup">
    <span tabindex = "1">Online</span>
    <span tabindex = "2">Offline</span>
    <span tabindex = "3">Connecting</span>
    <span class = "icon"></span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.buttonGroup > .icon {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.buttonGroup > span:nth-of-type(-n + 3) {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 10px;
    outline: 0;
    font: bold 12px/20px Sans-Serif;
    vertical-align: top;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #ccc;
}

.buttonGroup > span:first-of-type:focus ~ .icon {
    background-color: green;
}

.buttonGroup > span:nth-of-type(2):focus ~ .icon {
    background-color: gray;
}

.buttonGroup > span:nth-of-type(3):focus ~ .icon {
    background-color: orange;
}
```

Here's a solution that persists button state: http://jsfiddle.net/nshvuf44/.

HTML:

```
<div class = "buttonGroup">
    <label for = "online">Online</label>
    <label for = "offline">Offline</label>
    <label for = "connecting">Connecting</label>

    <input type = "radio" id = "online" name = "state" />
    <input type = "radio" id = "offline" name = "state" />
    <input type = "radio" id = "connecting" name = "state" />

    <span class = "icon"></span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.buttonGroup > .icon {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.buttonGroup > label {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 10px;
    outline: 0;
    font: bold 12px/20px Sans-Serif;
    vertical-align: top;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #ccc;
}

.buttonGroup > input {
    display: none;
}

.buttonGroup > #online:checked ~ .icon {
    background-color: green;
}

.buttonGroup > #offline:checked ~ .icon {
    background-color: gray;
}

.buttonGroup > #connecting:checked ~ .icon {
    background-color: orange;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work if the page has other controls on the page that will take the focus.

Comment: This solution meets the specs.  Every time a "button" is clicked the `.icon` background color changes.  If the original poster wishes the state of the clicked button to be retained, then the specification needs to be adjusted.  And, even with revised specs, it is still quite doable using only CSS - see my updated post.